# How do I stop iPhones from resizing my background images?

Tags: iphone, css, image

You can see the problem at myspace.com/dejaentenduband

on an iPhone, the background image is shrunk by what appears to be nearly 50%

I haven't had this issue on on other browser. I'd expect the background to simply be cropped where it doesn't fit the screen.

Since it is unusual behavior, and apple must realise this, I'm hoping there is a pure css or HTML based solution. Should I be defining something differently or giving my page's body a particular attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out that this has nothing to do with the viewport.

there's an article on it here:

http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/

one of the limitations of an iphone is stated by Mac:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html

JPEG images larger than 2 megapixels are subsampled - that is, decoded to a reduced size

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to [configure the page's viewport](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the background image is taller than 1000px it will resize to the width of the viewport. Try reducing the height and see if this has an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the easiest fix for this. Just open the image through Photoshop and save the image using the "Save for Web & Devices"..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest fix of ALL:

Open Fireworks, export your image as a 32 bit png, and use that png in your background. IOS doesn't scale THAT. Works like a charm, and the size is about the same as a jpg with 100% quality (slightly smaller actually)